# Select only specific properties from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's  say I create object like this:

```
updates.push({
      id: this.ids[i],
      point: point,
      value: value
    });
```

Later on I want to use `JSON.stringify` on `updates` object, however I need only
`point` and `value`  like:

```
updates[{point: 1, value: 12}, {point: 2, value: 24}]
```

What's the best ES6 solution for that?

I looked at some examples with delete, but that's not what I actually need, as I do not want to delete ids.

Comment: So clone it and delete it or just copy what you need.

Comment: you simply clone the object ignoring certain fields before stringify

Comment: `JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])`, leverage replacer

Comment: Please clarify: Do you specifically just want `point` and `value`, always? Or do you want every property except ID?

Comment: Only point and value, always

Comment: Ah, then mine is probably not the best way to go.  The answer does not have to do with deleting the `id` as much as choosing the `point` and `value` properties.

Comment: though to @ScottSauyet credit, the title of the post should probably be modified then

Comment: I've updated the title to be more indicative of OP's intentions.

Comment: Thank you for answers, I'll keep them in mind. All helped a ton!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following :

```
JSON.stringify(updates.map(({point,value})=>({point,value})));
```

```js
let updates = [{id : 1, point : 1, value: 2},{id : 1, point : 1, value: 2}];
console.log(JSON.stringify(updates.map(({point,value})=>({point,value}))));
```

Answer (score 4):

If `updates` is an array. Then you might want something like this:

```
const newArrayWithoutId = updates.map(({ point, value }) => {
  return {
    point,
    value,
  }
}
```

Comment: `({id, ...rest}) => ({...rest})` would be cleaner still.

Comment: i think it depends on what you're trying to do.. but i agree. I would make the argument that my version is more readable and more specific. If the application changes and `updates` items starts to contains more properties. You would get all of them, when possibly the OP just wants the `point` and `value` data points only.

Comment: @tylerroper makes a good point in the other answer post though.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree about readability, but yes, the correct answer depends a bit more on the real-wold scenario.  I make the same point in a comment on my own answer.

Comment: OP has now specified that they just need `point` and `value`, always, so +1 here too. I agree that this answer is a bit more reader friendly, being that the next developer knows exactly what the returned properties will be, whereas the object spread alternative only tells them one property that it *won't* have.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I apologize - I just edited the title, so I hope that doesn't undermine the usefulness of your answer. As mentioned, I still really like your answer, it's unfortunate that we didn't know OP's true intentions initially. Feel free to roll the title back if you think it's more appropriate.

Comment: @TylerRoper: No worries.  I'm keeping mine here after all the conversation related to it, but I upvoted both of the other current answers.

Answer (score 3):

Just `({id, ...rest}) => ({...rest})` is too short for an answer, so how about this?

```js
const withoutId = ({id, ...rest}) => ({...rest})

const vals = [
  {id: 'a', point: 1, value: 'foo'},
  {id: 'b', point: 2, value: 'bar'},
  {id: 'c', point: 3, value: 'baz', meaning: 42}
]

const reduced = vals.map(withoutId)

console.log(reduced)
```

Comment: OP's title is about "removing a property", so I think the real solution should provide "Everything *except* `id`". This is the only answer so far that has achieved that without hard-coding any property names. +1 from me - though this is all based on speculation unfortunately. OP will need to clarify.

Comment: Yes, although it's never clear with small examples whether the real-world case would involve removing a few or keeping a few values, or worst, somewhere in between.